# Flutter video_player not playing video on Vivo Device

Tags: android, flutter, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, video-player

Flutter video_player plugin is not able to play video on a specific device.

Device: Vivo 1601

Video keeps buffering and not playing.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? Does it do the same thing in debug, profile, and release mode?

Comment: Hello Joe, Actually I don't have that specific device with me. One of my user is having that problem. Video_player keeps buffering on that device.